# Limits and derivatives in trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that:

> $$ \cos x \sin A - 
> \sin x \cos A =  
> -2\ 
> \sin\left(\dfrac{x-A}{2}\right) \cdot 
> \cos\left(\dfrac{x-A}{2}\right) $$

Comment: Even if you have met this **trigonometrical identity** in the framework of "limits" and "derivatives", your title is completely inadequate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we get
$$\cos(x)\sin(A)-\sin(x)\cos(A)=-\sin(x-A)=-2\sin(\frac{x-A}{2})\cos(\frac{x-A}{2})$$

Comment: yes it was a typo, just corrected